# Как удвоить символ с помощью копирования?

Tags: c++, c, строки

Как удвоить символ с помощью **memmove**?

Исходная строка: Привет, меня зовут Игоша!
Конечная строка: Привет, ме**н**ня зовут Игоша!

Comment: Зависит от кодировки. Для utf-8 (и массива с парой "лишних" байт в конце) подойдет `memmove(s + 20, s + 18, strlen(s + 18) + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 memmove(str + 11, str + 10, strlen(str));
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Удвоить текущий? Но, может, имеет смысл рассмотреть более общую задачу вставки символа?

В любом случае вам нужно, чтобы выделенной памяти было достаточно, так что, например,

```
char s[] = "Привет, меня зовут Игоша!";
```

не пройдет — вы получите выход за пределы выделенной памяти. А вот так

```
char s[27] = "Привет, меня зовут Игоша!";
```

как раз  остается место для еще одного символа.

Дальше смысл примерно такой

```
Привет, меня зовут Игоша!
          ^---->  копируем на один символ вправо
```

при этом мы получим строку

```
Привет, мення зовут Игоша!
```

Но если нужен *произвольный символ*, то теперь его можно просто записать в строку в нужном месте.

Копировать надо с помощью `memmove`, так как только эта функция корректно обрабатывает копирование перекрывающихся интервалов.

Еще вопрос в кодировке русского текста... Если это однобайтовая кодировка типа ANSI (1251) или OEM (866), то дело одно, а если многобайтовая типа UTF-8, то тут надо делать несколько иные действия для учета того, что один символ не равен одному байту...

Answer (score 0):

```
    char str[] = "Hello,my name is Igosha!";
    memmove(&str[12], &str[11], 3);
    std::cout << str;
```